# Not able to access Mysql from Linux CLI

Tags: mysql

I am a beginner in linux and Mysql. I have installed mysql server on ubuntu. When I try to run it using the command `sudo mysql`I get the error message as follows
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

How do I resolve this issue?

Thanks & Regards,
Sameera

I am unable to provide any password as I am yet to create a user in Mysql. Without access it I am unable to create a user and password.

Answer (score 0):

You should first try to reset root password.
You can find the instructions to reset mysql root password on linux at this link
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/resetting-permissions.html

Once the new password of root is set, you can then use this command to connect mysql client at linux cli

sudo mysql -u root -p